# Quadratic equations over Gaussian integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computational-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Given an equation $x^2\equiv(a+ib)\bmod(c+id)$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$ holds, how to test if the equation has solutions and how to find the solutions in polynomial in $\log(|abcd|)$ time if $c+id$ is a Gaussian prime and $p=c^2+d^2$ is a prime congruent to $1\bmod 4$?

Comment: Note $\mathbb{Z}/(c+id)\mathbb{Z}$ is a finite field of size $p$, and any algorithm that works in a finite field will work here. In particular you can use binary exponentiation to check if a solution exists: $(a+ib)^{(p-1)/2}\bmod {c+id}$ is congruent to $1$ if $a+ib$ is a square.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky How to handle when $p$ is not a prime?

Comment: @Turbo Finding modular square roots is essentially equivalent to factorization (under some form of randomized polynomial time reductions, not sure about the details). I don't know about just determining existence.

Comment: @wojowu I see.. then for prime case, how do we actually find the roots?

Comment: Tonelli-Shanks.

Comment: @Turbo To make things concrete, there is an explicit isomorphism $\phi\colon \mathbb{Z}[i]/(c+id)\mathbb{Z}[i]\to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ given by $\phi(a+ib)=a+xb$ where $x\bmod p$ is a squareroot of $-1$ (and, as Peter Taylor indicated, this root can be computed efficiently).

Comment: This has grown out of the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699383/square-root-operations-modulo-gaussian-integers/